# Possible to take half of Cassandra nodes down without affecting the application?

Tags: cassandra

If there is a 4 node Cassandra cluster, is it possible to configure Cassandra in a way to have half of the nodes down (two in this case) without affecting the applications?

Also how long can nodes be down without Cassandra cancelling the write queue?

Comment: there are many factors there - what consisency levels are used, single-token/vnodes, etc. Please provide more information

Comment: Yes, As Alex we need to consider many factors. please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the client CL and DC replication factor.

Let's assume the RF is 4 (all), if the client has a CL=ONE or LOCAL_ONE, the application would not notice any issues. Any other client CL would have problems (e.g. cl=local_quorum of 4 is 3, allowing only a single node to be down).

Let's assume the RF=1 or 2. If CL=ONE or LOCAL_ONE, the application would be unaffected by queries that only manipulate data on the available nodes. However, any access to rows that only exist on the unavailable nodes would be impacted. In other words, CL=ONE or LOCAL_ONE only works if you're manipulating data that has at least one node available to return the response (You only need ONE to respond in this scenario). If the rows you're querying are on both of the unavailable nodes, you'll get an error stating something like: Expected response of 1, received 0.

Many applications configure CL to be some sort of quorum (local or not) - so in that case, the application would certainly fail unless you had RF=5 (so at least 5 nodes). Quorum of 5 is 3, allowing for 2 nodes to fail.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you are talking about all four nodes in one data centre, if you set your replication factor to 3 or greater and your read and write consistency level to ONE.

For writes the nodes that are up will store *hints* for the nodes that are down, so when they come back up they can write the data. How long the nodes store these hints can be set in `cassandra.yaml`.